# Linux bash script for oldest file in a folder + return value if folder is empty

Tags: linux, script, zabbix

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) 
I need to find a folders oldest file and print it out in unixtime. I did get the job done with this one liner: 
`find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -i stat -c "%Y" '{}' | sort | head -n 1`
 (the $1 is for Zabbix)

But when the folder becomes empty the value also seem to be empty and my monitoring software, Zabbix, cant handle empty values so I need it to, for example print out number 0 if the folder is empty.

Okay so next I composed this beautiful script but as you all can see it's pretty shait. So could anyone help me out with this? 
FYI. I started messing around with linux two days ago so please bear with me :P

```
#!/bin/bash    
export fileage
fileage=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -i stat -c "%Y" '{}' | sort | head -n 1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "0"  
else
   echo "fileage"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**find** can print any of the 3 timestamps a file/directory can have.
You just have to use **-printf** with the appropriate format sequence: **%C@** or **%A@** or **%T@** (see the detail is **man find**).

As for empty directories, checking if **$?** is 0 can be misleading because 0 return code means "nothing bad has happened", and an empty directory does not count "something bad", it's just a special but normal case.
But you can store the OUTPUT of find (and the following commands in the pipe) and check if it is empty or not.

Like

```
fileage=$(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@\n" | sort | head -n 1)
if [ -z "fileage" ]; then
  echo 0
else
  echo $fileage
fi
```

or, if you like to be short:

```
fileage=$(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@\n" | sort | head -n 1)
echo ${fileage:=0}
```

Nevertheless, be careful if you really want to see "oldest file" because that would mean reading the *creation time* of the file and that is not stored. You could have the oldest file with the newest of all the three timestamps.

Comment: Cheers for your help!                                                                              Now I have a different problem. I have the script in folder /home/logia/zabbix/script/fileage.bash.                                                         I gave it executable rights using chmod +x and when I run the script by writing /home/logia/zabbix/script/fileage.bash it gives me an error             "-bash: /home/logia/zabbix/script/fileage.bash: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" and I transferred the file in ASCII format. Any advices?

Comment: Your script file is in DOS format, the lines are terminated by 0xOD 0x0A characters and not only by 0x0A. You can help this using sed (requires some exprience), other shell tools or your editor if it has the feature of setting line termination. I can tell you how to do it using vi. Type everything as written (without the numbers) 1) vi script 2) :set fileformat=dos 3) :wq

Comment: Thanks you bro, now it works! Changing the EOL conversion option from notepad++ did the trick